# Run multiple macros when cell detects change

Tags: vba, excel

I've recently been having difficulty running this macro that auto-runs when it detects a modification to a particular range of cells. So far, the first sub that I have inserted into this macro in the sheet code has run smoothly... i tried to replicate this same macro for the other sub and it did not work.

I'm thinking it might be the Elseif that is not working for this particular sheet code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Target
    If Not Intersect(cell, Range("C5:C1000")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim currCell As Range
        For Each currCell In ActiveSheet.Range("D5:D1000")
            If IsEmpty(currCell) And currCell.Offset(0, -1) = "Open" Then
                currCell = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")
            End If
        Next currCell
    ElseIf Not Intersect(cell, Range("C5:C1000")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim currCell2 As Range
        For Each currCell2 In ActiveSheet.Range("I5:I1000")
            If IsEmpty(currCell2) And currCell2.Offset(0, -5) = "Closed" Then
                currCell2 = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")
            End If
        Next currCell2
```

Comment: Yeah, you cannot put a `Next` inside of an `If/Then` like that.

Comment: Is part of your code missing? You have "For Each cell In Target" but no "Next cell", and there is no "end sub"

Comment: I don't think the code in the `ElseIf` section will ever run as it has the same condition as the initial `If`. So if that condition is true then the first code will run and if it is false, neither section will run.

Comment: Part of my code was missing "   End If
    Next currCell2
    End If
Next cell
    
End Sub"

Comment: @Oilprogramming, go ahead and edit that in.  I also think you need to provide more detail as it's not clear what your asking.  In what way did it "not work"?  What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I got it to work! Thanks for all your help!